# PHP: Always display decimal places in EXCEL even Zeroes

Tags: php, excel

I am generating an excel sheet using `Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel`. Code looks like this

```
    $filename = "Stack_Rank_ReportV2_(".$fromdate."_".$todate.").xls";
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");    
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");      
        header("Expires: 0");

        $head_row  = "Emp. ID"."\t";
        $head_row .= "Employee Name"."\n";
        echo $head_row;

        $user_row = $users[$userid]['empid']."\t";
        $user_row .= $users[$userid]['name']."\n";
        echo $user_row;
```

The problem is that the decimal points are ignored by excel if it is zero say `1.000` becomes `1` but shows properly if it is `1.001`.
I'm looking for something like `setFormatCode()` that is there in `PHPEXCEL`. Is there a way to acheive this?

Comment: Are you using a library to generate the excel file?

Comment: @RayA i'm just straight up generating file type `vnd.ms-excel` as you can see in the above piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but it will have to be a string instead of a float.

```
$nums = [1, 10.00, 10.001, 1.000, 0];

function f($num){
    if(!strpos($num, '.')) $num = number_format($num, 2, '.', '');
    return $num;
}

foreach ($nums as $num) echo f($num)."\n";
```

Output:

```
1.00
10.00
10.001
1.00
0.00
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a4a9d348fa27f334077acaa1863fa59cc59f21fb)

You can't see it but the types are diffrent

```
string(4) "1.00"
string(5) "10.00"
float(10.001)
string(4) "1.00"
string(4) "0.00"
```

Not really a "big deal" for PHP but something to be aware of.  PHP won't display a float with the zeros.  Once it converts to string the 0's are removed, which is why `strpos` above works when the number version has the `.`.  I should add when you do echo or otherwise output a float with 0's PHP will convert it to a string and remove them, so you have to convert it yourself using number format etc...